# Autocorrect using Apache LUCENE

Tags: lucene, autocorrect

I am using apache lucene for a project to do the autocorrect functionality. I need the suggestions to come up only if the spelling is wrong. 
In apache  Lucene, I can see that suggesions are coming up even if the spelling is typed right and wrong. How can I eliminate suggestions for right entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it....

there is a function called SpellChecker.exist()